# How to read a 2 column file and pass each column as a paired input for GNU parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a list of paired files in a directory that I put inside a file (using `paste`)

```
cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3
./ID1_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz    ./ID1_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
./ID2_L3_R1_001.fastq.gz    ./ID2_L3_R2_001.fastq.gz
./ID3_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz    ./ID3_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

You can see that the pair is between **R1** and **R2**.

This is just for testing as this is going to be passed to another command. The command below just paste line by line.

```
parallel -j 1 "echo {}" ::::  <(cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3)
```

This one duplicates the files

```
parallel -j 1 "echo {} {}" ::::  <(cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3)
```

This doesn't work:

```
parallel -j 1 "echo {1} {2}" ::::  <(cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3)
```

Basically, what I want is that each line of the `list.files.r12.txt` file could be executed in parallel. This is the desired output:

```
program ... ./ID1_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz ./ID1_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
program ... ./ID2_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz ./ID2_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
program ... ./ID3_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz ./ID3_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Comment: why not use `xargs` instead? `printf '%s\0' dir/* | xargs -0 -n 2 echo`

Comment: I'm not sure what xargs does, but I want to run 4 programs at the same time, with each having 8 cores (so I'm going to reserve 36 cores, 4 for running the commands in parallel and 8 cores for each of the parallel sequences (4*8 = 32 cores). Can xargs do that?

Comment: I have added `gnu-parallel` tag. Delete it if you can't use `parallel` in your environment. Good luck.

Comment: With GNU and BSD `xargs` you can run 4 instances of `program` with `... | xargs -0 -n 2 -P 4 program`. Now, how many cores each instance will use is not defined by `xargs`, nor `parallel`

Comment: If you do not need shell, `xargs` is way simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3 |
   parallel --colsep '\t' echo
```

```
cat list.files.r12.txt | head -n3 |
   parallel --colsep '\t' echo one:{1} two:{2}
```

When you have paired end reads you can normally do:

```
parallel --plus echo read:{} paired:{/_R1_/_R2_/} ::: *__R1_*
```

This way you avoid the pasting.